# Can't ssh into my ec2 instance after stopping and starting it

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I had to start and stop my ec2 instance because I ran a script that caused it to freeze.

After doing this, I can't login to my ec2 instance. Any ideas of what could be the issue here? The error that I'm getting is:

```
ssh: connect to host ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

**EDIT Adding Security Rules**

SSH
TCP
22
0.0.0.0/0

HTTP
TCP
80
0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Your instance probably has a new IP. Check your console to see if you are connecting with the correct IP.

Comment: Yes, I accounted for this. Still not too sure why I can't ssh.